# Using User controls in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, user-controls

I'm migrating the MVC application into .Net Core. So I have some user controls in the MVC application so I have to use those in the .net core application. Can anyone please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asp.net core does not support user controls.**

As a substitute, you can use  **ViewComponent** , **partial view** or **Custom TagHelper** to do it's job.

They can be **reusable**, just like user control.

So you should understand the logic in User Controls, and then apply the logic in these ways:

[ViewComponent tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Partial View tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Custom TagHelper](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-tag-helpers-with-asp-net-core-mvc/)

I suggest you trying ViewComponent first, because it is more suitable when you want to

write some complex logic, and it always renders chunk rather than a whole process.